# Bootstrap footer navigation bar problems

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, footer

For some reason, my footer navigation bar when in full desktop mode is being displayed with some menu links being displayed on the same line as the navbar header and then centering themselves vertically when past the navbar header...I just want them to be displayed vertically in a line and cented....

```
(currently displayed)
Navbar Header Link 1
     Link 2
     Link 3

(How I actually want it displayed)
Navbar Header 
     Link 1
     Link 2
     Link 3
```

```
<div class = "container-fixed">
        <div class = "row" height = 100%>
            <div class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                <!-- Footer About Dropdown -->
                <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" id = "bottomabout">
                    <div class = "container">
                       <div class = "navbar-header">
                            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbar-collapse">
                                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                            <h3 class = "text-center">
                                About Us
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "aboutcollapse">
                            <ul class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        OUR STORY
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        BABY REGISTRY
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        STORE LOCATOR
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        TESTIMONIALS
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-sm-2">
                <!-- Service Footer Dropdown -->
               <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" id = "bottomservice">
                    <div class = "container">
                       <div class = "navbar-header">
                            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbar-collapse">
                                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                            <h3>
                                Service
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "aboutcollapse">
                            <ul class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        CONTACT US
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        ORDER STATUS
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        FAQ
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        SHIPPING POLICY
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        RETURN POLICY
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        NEWSLETTER
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        MY ACCOUNT
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        LIVE CHAT
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav> 
            </div>
            <!-- Shop Footer Dropdown -->
            <div class = "col-sm-2">
                <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" id = "bottomshop">
                    <div class = "container">
                       <div class = "navbar-header">
                            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbar-collapse">
                                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                            <h3>
                                Shop
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "aboutcollapse">
                            <ul class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        BABY APPAREL
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        BABY GIFTS
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                       CHRISTENING
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        FURNITURE
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        BEDDING
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        DECOR
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        LIGHTING
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href = "">
                                        SALE
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a>
                                        BRANDS
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav> 
            </div>
            <!-- Contact Us Footer Dropdown -->
            <div class = "col-sm-2">
               <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" id = "bottomcontact">
                   <div class = "container">
                       <div class = "navbar navbar-header">
                           <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbar-collapse">
                                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                            <h3>
                                Contact Us
                            </h3>
                       </div>
                       <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse">
                           <ul class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked active">
                               <li>
                                   <h6>
                                      <b>
                                        BEAUTIFUL BEGINNINGS
                                      </b> 
                                   </h6>
                               </li>
                           </ul>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </nav>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-sm-2">
                <h3>
                    Follow Us
                </h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the container it will work as you wish.
check the following:

> ```
>             <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" id = "bottomabout">
>                    <div class = "navbar-header">
>                             <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbar-collapse">
>                                 <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
>                             </button>
>                             <h3 class = "text-center">
>                                 About Us
>                             </h3>
>                         </li>
>                         <li class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "aboutcollapse">
>                             <ul class = "nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
>                                 <li>
>                                     <a href = "">
>                                         OUR STORY
>                                     </a>
>                                 </li>
>                                 <li>
>                                     <a href = "">
>                                         BABY REGISTRY
>                                     </a>
>                                 </li>
>                                 <li>
>                                     <a href = "">
>                                         STORE LOCATOR
>                                     </a>
>                                 </li>
>                                 <li>
>                                     <a href = "">
>                                         TESTIMONIALS
>                                     </a>
>                                 </li>
>                             </ul>
>                         </div>
>
>                 </nav>
> ```

Comment: thank you! it almost worked now the first link of each section starts on the same line as the heading but at least everything isn't all over the place ahaha

Comment: actually i missed something it's working now and you're the best!! thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries, just don't forget to mark it as the right answer, thanks mate :)